# Why am I getting a Sysmalloc Error when using pthread?

Tags: pthreads, malloc

I am getting an error that says "malloc.c: 2399: sysmalloc: Assertion`(....) failed". I can't find a solution to this problem. I am trying to create a thread to calculate the dot product of two columns of a matrix, but suddenly I started receiving this error when I hadn't earlier.  When I undid my changes, the sysmalloc error kept showing up.   Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // miscellaneous code ommitted // 

    int* firstFileValues = openFirstFile(matrix1File); 
    int* secondFileValues = openSecondFile(matrix2File); 

    // create the matrix 
    struct Matrix* firstMatrix; 
    firstMatrix = matrix_init_with_list(firstFileValues); 

    struct Matrix* secondMatrix; 
    secondMatrix = matrix_init_with_list(secondFileValues); 

    printMatrix(firstMatrix); 
    printMatrix(secondMatrix);

    printf("here"); 

    messageBuffer message; 
    message = createMessageBuffer(1, 0, 5, 5, 1); 

    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        message.data[i] = i; 
    }

    printf("creating thread\n"); 
    pthread_t thread; 
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, packagingThread, &message); 
    pthread_join(thread, NULL); 

}
```

The thread never runs and the execution always stops right when it is about to create the tread.  Weirdly, when I comment out the code for creating the second matrix, the code runs perfectly fine, even the thread.  Can someone help me? Thank you!

Edit Update: added matrix_init_with_list() code.  The list values is formatted like so: 
    index0: the number of rows in the matrix 
    index1: the number of cols in the matrix
    index2: the first value in the matrix
          .
          . 
          .
    indexN: the nth value in the matrix

```
struct Matrix* matrix_init_with_list(int* values) {

    // allocate the matrix 
    struct Matrix* theMatrix; 
    theMatrix = (struct Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(struct Matrix)); 

    // assign rows and values 
    int rows = values[0]; 
    int cols = values[1]; 
    theMatrix->rows = rows; 
    theMatrix->cols = cols; 

    // allocate the values matrix
    theMatrix->values = (int**) malloc(rows * sizeof(int*)); 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        theMatrix->values[i] = (int*) malloc(cols * sizeof(int)); 
    }

    // assign the values 
    int j; 
    int count = 2; 
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            theMatrix->values[i][j] = values[count]; 
            count++; 
        }
    }

    return theMatrix; 


}
```

Comment: You might want to include the code for matrix_init_with_list(...) and any other helper functions - since removing a call to it makes things work ok, it might be the source of your issue.

Comment: Ok, I added the matrix_init_with_list() function, let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: Its still kinda hard to point to something specific, but the code looks rather risky given there are no bounds checks or anything - have you stepped through this in a debugger? My guess is one of your input files isn't being interpreted as expected, and you're trying to allocate too much data (or a negative number of bytes).